# same form data, different actions on two separate submit buttons

Tags: php, javascript

I have what is essentially a shopping cart that needs to have two separate checkout options. The first of which takes the user away from the site, but form data must be posted.

How can I create two submit buttons that will send the same form data to their own separate page?

Comment: You mean that you _have to_ post he data to either your site (a) or to another site (b) which you do not control, i.e. a switch in one of your server side scripts on (a) is _not_ what you're looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have 2 submit buttons on the same page and both of them have the same form if that is so, this should do the trick.

```
if(isset($_POST['name1'])) {
//do stuff
}

if(isset($_POST['name2'])) {
//do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Well you could do this: -

define your form with action=""

then have two buttons: -

```
<input type="button" value="button1" onClick="this.form.action='your_first_action_url'; this.form.submit()">
<input type="button" value="button2" onClick="this.form.action='your_second_action_url';this.form.submit()">
```

Answer (score 2):

you could set an onclick handler to the buttons and change the form action dinamically.
I'm giving this answer because you have the javascript tag and i assume the external site receives the parameters via POST METHOD so you could not make a redirection in php

But i wouldn't trust in this because it require the users having javascript enabled...