# php contact form, two submit buttons

Tags: php, html, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [same form data, different actions on two separate submit buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617160/same-form-data-different-actions-on-two-separate-submit-buttons)
>   [upload form within a contact form, the upload form submit keeps submitting the whole form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492594/upload-form-within-a-contact-form-the-upload-form-submit-keeps-submitting-the-w)

I have a file upload section within a php contact form, the submit button for a file upload,  submits the form instead. how can i distinguish between the two submit buttons?

It's basically two POST forms, the file upload one within the php contact form.

Comment: You can't have nested forms in HTML if you want to properly send the data to PHP.

Comment: original code can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492594/upload-form-within-a-contact-form-the-upload-form-submit-keeps-submitting-the-w

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst It has less to do with PHP than the fact that nested forms are just not valid HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Just give each one a name:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Submit 1">
<input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit 2">

if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
  // submit 1 pressed
}
else if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
  // submit 1 pressed
}
```

Comment: the php scrip for the upload form is on upload.php and the contact form on contact.php, so what would i place under submit 1 pressed?

Comment: the code can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492594/upload-form-within-a-contact-form-the-upload-form-submit-keeps-submitting-the-w

Answer (score 2):

Example Form:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Button1">
<input type="submit" name="submit2" value="button2">
</form>
```

Then work with the `name=""` server sided..

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit1']))
{
 echo "Button1 Is Set <br>";
}
if (isset($_POST['submit2']))
{
 echo "Button2 Is Set <br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: the php scrip for the upload form is on upload.php and the contact form on contact.php, so what would i place under submit 1 pressed?

Comment: So the user is viewing two different forms..? if that's so, then just do your HTML Form like normal; but just keep your form button names unique.

Comment: the code is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492594/upload-form-within-a-contact-form-the-upload-form-submit-keeps-submitting-the-w

Comment: Why have you created two questions on the same topic..? and your answer is listed in the two answers provided.. Have two buttons on your HTML Form, one to manage the file upload; with some js/ajax keeping the page alive whilst the upload is taking place; then when done, the user presses button 1 and it checks for an upload, and submits the form.

Comment: would the entire php code on upload_ac.php go between the { and  }?

Comment: If you don't know what you are doing, then review php.net or use google for assistance for if clauses, submitting forms with php etc..